# Series of columns using Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have a observable collection of US StateCodes and a boolean indicator.  I data bound the collection to a view like so:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: states">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: stateName"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: useState"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

When I run it, I get the expected row per state:
[image]

But what I want is this:
[image]

I have been spending time binging around google and I am not having much luck.  Can anyone point me to a resource or give me some starter code to move me along?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move your foreach to the row instead of creating a row for each -

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: states">
        <td data-bind="text: stateName"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: useState"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this.  Here's hoping that we don't increase the number of US states in the near future..

```
<tbody >
    <tr data-bind="foreach: states.slice(0,11)">
        <td>
            <label data-bind="text:statesId" class="hidden"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: useState">
            <label data-bind="text:stateName"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: States.slice(12,23)">
        <td>
            <label data-bind="text:statesId" class="hidden"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: useState
            <label data-bind="text:stateName"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: States.slice(24,35)">
        <td>
            <label data-bind="text:statesId" class="hidden"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: useState
            <label data-bind="text:stateName"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: States.slice(36,47)">
        <td>
            <label data-bind="text:statesId" class="hidden"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: useState
            <label data-bind="text:stateName"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: States.slice(48,51)">
        <td>
            <label data-bind="text:statesId" class="hidden"></label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: useState
            <label data-bind="text:stateName"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Replace your slice with the length of states divided by 11 to have it be dynamic.  Each row has an $index value also if you make the rows dynamic you could use.  Could make this reusable for other data too then

Comment: Good call PW Kad!  Thanks for the help!